# Swiper Navigation not working at the first time

Tags: reactjs, navigation, swiper.js

If I click the navigation, it doesn't work at the first time. But after I swipe the slide, navigation works normally.
Plus, SwiperCore has a problem. If I add SwiperCore, the following error occurs.
*The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/swiper_react.js?v=95f6eae6' does not provide an export named 'default'
SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/swiper_react.js?v=95f6eae6' does not provide an export named 'default'*

Here's my code.

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper/modules";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";

<Swiper 
        className={`swiper-container ${S.swiper}`}
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
        navigation={{
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        }}
        loop={true}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
        >
...
</Swiper>
```

I want swiper navigation to work normally from the beginning.